# PyQGIS Creating Numpy Array from QByteArray (QgsRasterBlock.data()) and vice versa (QGIS3)

Tags: pyqgis, numpy, pyqgis-3

I am looking for a way to convert the values contained in a `QgsRasterLayer` object to a numpy array and vice versa without using any GDAL methods. 
To obtain the numpy array I go through `QgsRasterDataProvider` to `QgsRasterBlock` and then read the values into a numpy array through the `QgsRasterBlock.value(i,j)` method. This is not very elegant, but runs in an acceptable time.
Analogously - after working with the numpy array - I change the values in the `QgsRasterBlock` through the `QgsRasterBlock.setValue(i, j, value)` method, which takes forever and is not acceptable for my application... so I am looking for an alternative!

I've read that handling the pixel values in the `QgsRasterBlock` object as `QByteArrays` and creating numpy arrays directly from the `QByteArrays` is possible and efficient (as compared to the method described above).

So my first question: Is this true?

My second question: What does the numpy function to create an array from QByteArray look like? And which function can I use to go back again?